# Dataflow SQL Nested JSON Schema facing ambiguous field reference

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have following schema

```
Field name          Type    Mode       Policy tags   Description

root                STRUCT  REQUIRED                 Pub/Sub event timestamp

root.level1         STRUCT  NULLABLE    

root.level1.level2  STRING  NULLABLE
```

I can declare this in Bigquery UI successfully,
when I write SQL for Dataflow job, I get 
`Struct field name level1 is an ambiguous` error.

Does Dataflow SQL not support nested fields with more than one level?

[error message from Bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSYC8.png)

[even with select * though I Get valid message in UI in dataflow it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6tWa.png) with same error.

Comment: I believe you should use aliases to solve your issue, please check this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#ambiguous_aliases

Comment: no aliases did not help. this seems to nested support in dataflow sql.its not standard sql

Comment: Hi, can you provide the way that you defined that struct schema? Did you define that through the data catalog UI?